# How to implement SMSPluging in Cordova Application?

Tags: java, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am using **Cordova** Version 3.4.0. with CLI. The Concept of the project is to send SMS from **phoneGap** Application.

Below is the command used to create this project.

```
$ cordova create PluginExample com.example.pluginexample PluginExample 
$ cd PluginExample $ cordova platform add android 
$ cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.network-information 
$ cordova plugin add https://github.com/asanka-x/Phonegap-SMS.git 
$ cordova run android

*** smsplugin.send(number, message, '', success, error);
```

When i click on Send Button the below error message occurs, 
// `Error Message Failed: Class not found`

In ADT Eclipse, the below message is shown in LogCat
PluginManager -> exec() call to unknown plugin: SMSPlugin

How to implement this?

I have hosted the project in GitHub 
https://github.com/ideepakrnd/PhoneGapPlugin

Answer (score 0):

Check your plugin.xml file, I think have to add SMSPlugin in that.

```
<plugin name="SMSPlugin"   value="info.asankan.phonegap.smsplugin.SmsPlugin"/>
```